# is zookeeper a web service?

Tags: web-services, apache-zookeeper

Though it's not pretty clear to me what a web service is. And WIKI says that,  "A Web service is a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network." Can zookeeper, solrCloud, or cloudSolrServer, or any ZKClient be called a web service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could technically describe zookeeper as a service which can be offered over the web. However the term web service is generally considered to be associated with SOAP services. A SOAP service provides the ability for consumers (programs) to call into them across http with xm request and responses payloads in order to execute so e logic or retrieve some data.

Zoopkeeper is a product which exposes a number of web services that allow consumers to interact with it.